# How do I completely disable log rotation in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

In development I tail my application.log file but its hitting the max size pretty quickly.  I've tried the following configuration but the file is still getting rotated:

```
'log'=>array(
    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
    'routes'=>array(
        array(
            'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
            'levels'=>'error, warning, trace',
            'maxFileSize' => 99999,
            'maxLogFiles'=>1,
            'enabled'=>true,
        )
    )
)
```

Is it possible to completely, absolutely, no-questions-asked **STOP** Yii from rotating the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No (see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileLogRoute#rotateFiles-detail)

Long answer: No, but ...

Looks like there was a rotateByCopy flag added in Yii 1.1.14 that should help with your problem and allow you to just tail the main log file. Probably worth thinking about upgrading to Yii 1.1.14  Note: if you have boolean values in AR models that we're validated with integer rules previously, I've found those to be buggy in 1.1.14 Let me know if you do and I can send over the Github issue number for that bug.

Comment: Really? I'm quite enjoying it :-)

Comment: Its just like every other framework I've ever used. It'll get you to 80% of what you need REALLY fast. The next 10% will take some digging but it'll be doable. But that last 10%. It'll be like pulling teeth. Because inevitably you're going to need to do something that the framework wasn't designed for. And the time you'll spend trying to bend the framework into doing what you need will negate all those time savings you thought you were realizing when you started using it.

Comment: Yeah, understood on that.  Still, overall, at least on my end I think I'm still well ahead of where I would have been without it.

Comment: @DarrellBrogdon Also, random question, looks like you're in the Denver area? You on the Yii forums at all?  I've been wondering about starting a Yii meetup at some point in the Denver area ...

Comment: I only read the forums to try to find answers to a given problem.  I'm not familiar with any meetups in the area but I think meetup.com will give you a list if you search for one.  If there isn't one then you should definitely start it.